# Errors in compilation of SCALL.S SBREAK.S and CSR.S for risc v tool chain

Tags: assembly, message, riscv

I have been trying to compile SCALL.S, SBREAK.S and CSR.S tests but have been hitting into errors. The commands that I have been using are as follows

riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -c -m32 -I ../../../riscv-tests/ -o ../../../tests-build-xhay/scall.o ./scall.S

The errors seen are as shown below

```
./../rv64si/scall.S: Assembler messages:
./../rv64si/scall.S:33: Error: absolute expression required `li'
./../rv64si/scall.S:34: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression
./../rv64si/scall.S:36: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression
./../rv64si/scall.S:38: Error: Instruction csrw requires absolute expression
```

Could anyone point out what is the error here while running this commands or is there any other command that needs to be run.